# Who is Lex Luthor referring to at the end of Batman vs Superman?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, lex-luthor

In **Batman vs. Superman**, after Lex Luthor is put in prison. Batman visits him and he says "*Wherever you go. Whatever you Do. I'll be watching you.*" For which, Luthor replies...

> **Lex Luthor** : But, the bells have already been rung and they've heard it. Out in the dark. Among the stars. Ding dong, the God is dead. The bells, cannot be unrung! He's hungry. He's found us. And He's coming!

Who is Lex Luthor referring to? How does Lex Luthor know "He" is coming?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a setup for a sequel, so there is not enough information in the movie itself to say for sure, but it's a pretty good bet it'll be [Darkseid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkseid), since one of Batman's dreams featured [Darkseid's Omega symbol](http://www.cosmicbooknews.com/content/high-res-look-batman-vs-superman-omega-darkseid-reference) and winged beings that [look like parademons](http://www.techinsider.io/batman-v-superman-trailer-darkseid-2015-12), Darkseid's flying troops. See [this article](http://www.vulture.com/2016/03/batman-superman-dream-sequence.html) for some more discussion.

As for how Luthor would know, I can't say for sure, but KutuluMike pointed out in a comment that Warner Brothers has released [this deleted scene](http://io9.gizmodo.com/what-in-gods-name-is-going-on-in-this-batman-v-superman-1767524085) of Luthor on a Kryptonian ship, apparently communing with the hologram of a being that seems to be holding some [mother boxes](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Mother_Box) (the type of computer used on Darkseid's planet [Apokolips](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Apokolips), as well as his enemies on [New Genesis](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/New_Genesis)), some have speculated this being could be one of Darkseid's generals named [Steppenwolf](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Steppenwolf), or Darkseid's father [Yuga Khan](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Yuga_Khan_(New_Earth)). Hopefully the Justice League movie will explain Luthor's knowledge of the threat in more detail, along with explaining why Batman would be having some kind of precognition of the future when he isn't normally psychic, rather than just treating this stuff as "foreshadowing".

From [this page](http://junctiontonowhere.blogspot.com/2012_04_01_archive.html) which offers a good rundown on Darkseid, here's a shot from a comic of Darkseid showing off his Omega symbol:

[image]

And here's the same symbol burned into the landscape in Batman's dream:

[image]

Here are the parademons in the comic:

[image]

And some of the flying things in Batman's dream:

[image]

A close up showing what looks like glowing red eyes:

[image]

Comment: Batman didn't have a precognition. I believe that Batman v. Superman gave us a teaser for the **two** upcoming Justice League movies. The first was a setup for the parallel universe where Superman is evil due to Lois' death. In this universe the resistance group against evil Superman seeks help from ours. The second teaser was indeed the Darkseid saga, where imo would be the last movie (think of it like Avengers against Thanos). I have no proof for this, it's just my understanding of the movie/setting.

Comment: @Aventinus - Even if you're right, it would still be some sort of psychic awareness of the parallel universe since he saw it in a dream, even though psychic powers aren't normally part of Batman's abilities. Like I said, hopefully there'll be a good explanation for this.

Comment: there is a deleted scene that WB has released (you can find it on youtube) of Lex, in the ship, talking to someone that appears to be Darkseid or one of his cronies giving him a mother box.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : The "dream" was succeeded by Flash time travelling from the future to warn Batman.  It's well known that Flash's time travelling can cause ripple effects of out-of-time information.  So it is less likely that the Darkseid sequence is a "dream" and more likely to be an effect of Flash's use of time travel to communicate with Bruce.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : It's also not likely to be "psychic".  What we see is more to do with Flash than Batman.

Comment: @Praxis - How is the Flash sending a vision *into Batman's dream*? The Flash isn't psychic either.

Comment: @Hypnosifl : I just explained that to you.  It has been seen in the comics before that when Flash travels through time (which he can do, if he moves fast enough), there is a ripple effect, where people exposed to his time travel see events from the time where Flash is originating.  That is exactly what is happening here.  Did you not see Flash speaking to Bruce right after the "dream"?

Comment: @Praxis - Sorry, didn't notice you had posted two comments in a row, I just read the last one. Can you point to a specific comic where Flash's time traveling led information about the future to appear in the mind of someone who hadn't done any time traveling themselves, without any conventional explanation (like a time traveler communicating it to them)?

Comment: @Hypnosifl : Ah, that's okay.  Sure, I don't have an issue number off the top of my hand, but I'll find one and report back.  :-)

Comment: I believe that that scene was included in the extended cut, so in that sense it is no longer a deleted scene.

Answer (score 5):

The reference is to the villain Darkseid, hence setting up the sequel. There are many other references to Darkseid's coming in the movie itself such as the dream which Bruce had about a universe where Superman turned evil.

At the starting of the scene there is a big juicy reference for us, the Omega Symbol, symbolizing Darkseid.

The main question at the end of the movie is how in the world did Lex Luthor know about Darkseid? The answer is that there is a **deleted scene** in the movie.

Titled rightly so as *"Communion"*, it shows one of Darkseid's minions showing/telling Lex about Darkseid.

Answer (score 0):

Flash run to the future or other demsion. I beleive he was able to run fast enough to comunicate to bruce but not for long.

Comment: Could you add some more details to this?

Answer (score 0):

A simple explination of how batman saw the premonitions is that batman exist in multiple universes, what he might have been seeing is a parralel universe bleedover, like when a superhero sees a split decision alternate. Another explination is that some of the justice league has pyscic ability, and he was therefore recieving a jumbled up peice of a message from a possible future timeline from say aquaman or martian man hunter or even wonderwoman all of which at some point have shown psychic ability of one sort or another. Finally batman has come into contact with many pyschic heroes and villans, and it is entirely likely that they will use the ol magick explination (dc has been known to do that)  after all we are talking about a universe where wonder woman the daughter of a god exist (therefore gods and magick must also exist) some stuff to chew on in any case